# The purpose of ったって here?

Tags: grammar, meaning, syntax

I've read that ったって can mean 'even if' but I'm not sure how the grammar fits in the following:

> 良く解ったって話だ。

Is it saying "I'm talking about, even If you understand well"

Also is there a difference between ったって and たって?

Comment: You are thinking of a completely different kind of ったって.　Both kinds have already been discussed here (multiple times).

Comment: Example of the "even if" kind: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15272/making-sense-of-%e5%87%ba%e3%81%a6%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e5%be%85%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%81%a6