Does って have a conditional usage with verbs?
I was listening to a song (‘Found And Lost’ by Survive Said The Prophet) and the first lyric is:
「かかってこいよ」と叫んだってそう思っていない時もあってしまうんでしょ
I can understand the meaning of the sentence, however I’m a little confused over the meaning of 「叫んだって」as I’m not sure if って has a conditional usage with verbs. I know that だって can be used with nouns as a colloquial version of でも, for example 「誰だって」, but i’m not sure if the same is applicable for verbs.

Partly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15272/43676

This だ is part of the past form of 叫ぶ. And this って is a conjunctive meaning "even if". 叫んだって is an informal/colloquial (and slightly more emphatic) version of 叫んでも.

Some questions about って
How to parse ～なくたって?
What is the meaning of「って」here?

Note that this だ is completely different from だ as a copula, and this って is completely different from って as a topic marker or って as a quotative particle.
